# Ubuntu file manager with more zoom

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, icons, filemanager, zooming

I want to go over a folder with images and copy some of them to a different folder. I am working on a laptop screen and I want to see the image thumbnails zoomed bigger.

I tried the file managers I know of. Nautilius, Thunar, PCManFM. All of them zoom only to some extent and then stop. For example, the default nautilus only allows me to zoom up to 133%.  Dolphin doesn't show preview at all. I remember file managers a few years ago used to zoom much bigger.

Is there any file manager or any setting in one of the above file managers that will allow me to zoom the images like to 2 columns?

Version: Ubuntu 18.04

[image: nautilus]

[image: dolphin]

Comment: i am using nautilus as default file manager and it is showing me the option after 133%, 267%  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SGp2.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/0klUS.png

Comment: Re. "Dolphin doesn't show preview at all." did you set `Previews` in `Dolphin Preferences`?

Comment: Few years the zoom was bigger? That probably appeared so, because you had a lower resolution screen. No, unfortunatelly the enlargement is limited.

Comment: @PRATAP attached screenshot. The plus button is greyed out and unable to click. What version of nautilus are you using? Mine is 3.26.3

Comment: Gnome 3.28.2, recently i have done some changes to nautilus.xml schema but i dont know due to this it is shown 267% or not. i have not checked it whether it is activated before editing nautilus.xml schema or not

Comment: @DKBose For some reason Previews is empty and there is no option to add or set anything. Please see attached screenshot

Comment: Interesting. It's likely that something, I don't know what, is missing from your system. Because Dolphin on Kubuntu does have a long list to choose from.

Comment: I just posted a solution for this question at https://askubuntu.com/a/1097952/100356. (I didn't realize this question was older).

Comment: With Caja you can get thumbnails as large as you want : https://askubuntu.com/a/1459134/607630

Answer (score 3):

This answer is to address solely

> Dolphin doesn't show preview at all.

I have Kubuntu 18.04 and Dolphin is the default file manager. In **Configure Dolphin > Dolphin Preferences > General > Preview**, one has a choice of what one wants to preview:

[image: Dolphin Preview]

For the purpose of this answer, I've chosen to preview `SVG` files.

Looking at the contents of `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/apps` because I have LibreOffice installed, the smallest view, 16px, looks like this:

[image: Smallest]

whereas one can adjust the slider in the lower right of the window to 256px:

[image: 256px]

Answer (score 2):

MATE DE and Cinnamon have file-managers with 400% preview zoom:

- Caja

  [image: Caja on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]
- Nemo

  [image: Nemo on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]