# Nautilus: Show image thumbnails at more than 200% size

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I would like to delete some images with nautilus.

I increased the size to 200%.

My monitor has a high resolution and the image are too small for me.

I would like to increase the size even more, but it seems to be impossible.

See screenshot.

[image: image thumbnails in Nautilus]

Is there a particular reason why increasing beyond 200% is not possible?

Comment: It can go up to 267%. Would that be enough, or are you looking for even larger?

Comment: Is it not possible to use an image viewer instead? It should be possible to "scroll" through images with the forward and back arrow keys, deleting the ones you don't want. The Dolphin file manager can scale thumbnails from 16px up to 256px but even that may not be enough to distinguish between two closely similar images.

Comment: And a similar question was asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081905/ubuntu-file-manager-with-more-zoom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nautilus Thumbnails Size Fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539802/nautilus-thumbnails-size-fix)

Comment: @vanadium maybe this work by using dconf. But that is nothing that my grandma would understand. An simple solution would be nice.

Comment: Don't worry. The setting is not anymore available in more recent nautilus versions, so changing is not directly an option anymore.

Comment: With Caja you can get thumbnails as large as you want : https://askubuntu.com/a/1459134/607630

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost always modern glossy GNOME use strange non-intuitive methods for simple problems.
Seems to be limited by design.
You can see other snap problem [as a good example of modern Nautilus "design"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1088630/66509).

It is time to switch to MATE or Cinnamon with their file-managers

- Caja

  [image: Caja on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]
- Nemo

  [image: Nemo on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS]

as both they have 400% zoom.

IMHO: if you want to use computer for work without bells and whistles - do not use GNOME at all.

Comment: If I ever switch away from Kubuntu, it would be to Ubuntu Mate. I have the minimal install of 18.10 in a VM and it's extremely user-friendly.

Comment: you said "if you want to use computer for work without bells and whistles - do not use GNOME at all." I want it to be simple and flexible. Thank you for your hint. I will have a look at Mate.

Comment: Not an answer to the question

Comment: @vanadium True this isn't an answer to the question but it is valid as a "Frame Challenge" as I just learned about yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098530/calculator-in-human-readable-format/1099283#1099283

Comment: Note: both caja and nemo have a dconf setting for custom thumbnail size if you want them really big (Nautilus doesn't have it anymore), but on nemo it's very buggy and unusable (at least on my XFCE system), whereas on caja it works fine.

Comment: I tried to give the most complete answer for todays file managers :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723732/220711

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04, the 400% zoom picture icons of caja have the same size as the 267% zoom of nautilus.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open a terminal and enter the following commands.

   In case you had enabled experimental views in Nautilus, we will first disable it.

   Then we set the desired "standard" icon thumbnail size. In this example, I've set thumbnail icon sizes to 400, but you can set it to whatever you want.

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size 400
   ```

   *Note, if you want to make the above changes using a GUI application instead of a terminal, you can disable experimental views in Nautilus' Preferences menu. Also, you can install the package `dconf-editor` and set both fields using the Dconf Editor's GUI.*
2. Restart

   To make the changes effective kill the Nautius process (or simply restart your computer).

   ```
   killall nautilus
   ```
3. Open Nautilus and navigate to the pictures folder you want to view.
4. Click on the "Icons View" grid in the header bar.

   [image: Click on the "Icons View" grid in the header bar]
5. Here is the thumbnails view with larger icons (100% = 400px). You can still scale them bigger or smaller from the **new large** default size you had set in step 1.

   [image: Nautilus with larger thumbnails icons]

Comment: Where this dconf/gsettings registry hack was documented? Please provide a link to official documentation.

Comment: You can query gsettings for the key description: `gsettings describe org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size`... "The default size of an icon for a thumbnail in the icon view when using NAUTILUS_ICON_SIZE_STANDARD size."

Comment: Nice! In step 2, terminating and restarting Nautilus instead of rebooting work well.

Comment: This solution is too much typing for my grandma

Comment: An edit and an upvote!  That's exactly what I was going to say!  **;-)**

Comment: This works and should become the accepted answer. It is enough to fully quit nautilus (killall nautilus) to have the change in effect on the next start. Side effect is that your icons do not scale accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the `killall nautilus` suggestion. I've added it to step #2.

Comment: Sometime between 18.04 and 19.10 the `thumbnail-size` key seems to have been dropped

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script that is easier for "grandma" to use:

### `zoom` - Script to set Nautilus Thumbnail size

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: zoom
# DESC: Change nautilus thumbnail size based on parameter 1
#       For Ask Ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934
#       /nautilus-show-images-with-more-than-200-size

# DATE: December 7, 2018

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: 'zoom 999'" 
    echo "Where 999 is zoom factor, eg 400 = 400% zoom"
    exit 1
fi

gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size "$1"
nautilus -q

exit 0
```

### Installation and Usage

Place the file `zoom` in your search path.

Mark the file executable with `chmod a+x /search-path-name/zoom`

Call the script from terminal using `zoom 999` where 999 is the zoom factor. For example `zoom 400` will have `nautilus` zoom by 400%.

The script can be enhanced to use `zenity` for a desktop shortcut with GUI pop up window that prompts for zoom percentage.

Comment: Grandma does not know how to create a script with gedit or vim. She does not know the command chmod(). She has old and weak eyes and all she wants is to see her grandson baby smile.

Comment: The bash script is an easy method of changing zoom factor over 200%. After one-time setup, to copy and paste above script, you won't have to type "hard to remember" commands in the terminal. I was mislead by the "grandma" comments because I thought you were going to set this up on her computer.

Comment: You are right. You can always walk around obstacles. Usability means for me "don't make me think". Maybe I should buy a commercial os for my grandma.

Comment: @guettli types the script for granny, sends it as an attachment in email, tells her to save in `~/bin` and types the `chmod` next time he visits granny.  **;-)**

Comment: This is still too complicated. This question received 8 up-votes. For me this means that there are other people who would like to increase the size of images even more. Is there no way to fix the root of the problem?

Comment: @guettli For me using `zoom 1000` increases 1000 % easily. The next step to make it easier would be to create desktop shortcut and GUI pop-up window to get the zoom factor. After that the final step would be to download Nautilus source code and patch it.

Comment: @guettli Wouldn't it be much easier if you open the image with image viewer? Navigate with arrow key and delete with Delete key. You gotta see the image in full screen or a maximized window, albeit you can only delete the images one by one. Though, it can be argued if you enlarge the thumbnails large enough you'll only can see them two or three at a time.

Comment: @aasril yes, I could use a different application. But why? Why not show the images bigger? What are the developers afraid of?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the output 'No such key “thumbnail-size”', in  Ubuntu 22.04. @aasril, one can embed custom thumbnails with MP4 file on Linux. Image view apps like Geeqie is not an option.