# Finder-like File manager that displays thumbnails arbitrarily large and allows free movement

Tags: lubuntu, filemanager

I'm looking for a file manager that will make it easier to match up photos.  I have two sets of photos with different names, and I need to rename like photos with similar names.  I have been using PCManFM, but it has two problems:

1. I can't make the thumbnails any large.  I need something like OS X where  I can set the dimensions of the thumbnails, for instance to 128x128 or 256x256 as my needs change.
2. I need to be able to drag files around and sit them arbitrarily on the desktop.  To do this I need to disable any automatic sorting or positioning of icons (also similar to what OS X provides).  In this way I can drag similar files next to each other before they get renamed.

PCManFM does not provide either functionality.  I have tried Thunar but while it lets me "zoom in" increasing the thumbnail size it isn't always enough.  In addition, it doesn't let me disable the automatic sorting and resizing.

I have seen Pantheon but I'm running LUbuntu and don't want to mess with trying to install it unless I know it will work.

Are there any other file managers that will do this which will easily run on LUbuntu 18.04?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1097939/66509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nemo**

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

View Menu -> Arrange Files -> Manually

Ctrl+= zooms in to a quite satisfactorally large icon for me.

Update: Nemo seemed to have a weird issue where it wouldn't generate/display thumbnails for all images, even if another file manager like PCManFM had already generated them. I tried linking ~/.cache/thumbnails to my ~/.thumbnails folder to no avail.  Finally, I installed **caja** which is another early fork of Nautilus from before the manual file arrangement was removed from it, and found that it works.