# 'unlock' nautilus icon zoom for HiDPI screens?

Tags: nautilus, 4k-monitor

I'm using a 32" 4k monitor, and if I try to browse a folder of [2000x1000px] image icons, the max zoom takes it up to about 1.5" diagonal, which is absurdly small.

For reference, browsing a similar set of icons in the Finder on an OSX machine plugged into this monitor, I can easily zoom multiple times this size.

Is there a way to 'unlock' icon zooming in Nautilus?

Comment: Used to be possible like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-images-with-more-than-200-size, but not anymore.

Comment: thanks @vanadium, is there another file manager I can configure for ubuntu 20.04 that isn't limited in this way?

Comment: Feel free to add a new question for possible advice on a file manager that does that.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, I have created a new question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1322106/942382