# file manager with icon zooming for HiDPI displays

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, hdpi

Previously, nautilus could be [configured to allow icon scaling at over %200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-image-thumbnails-at-more-than-200-size).  This appears to no longer available.

Is there a competing GUI file manager that is more flexible?

Comment: Hi, I believe the proper/intended way for hidpi displays would be to use the fractional scaling option in `(System )Settings->Display` - have you tried that yet? else there is caja and nemo, for latter there are a lot of howtos to replace nautilus with, like: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-replace-nautilus-with-nemo-file.html

Comment: thanks @d1bro, I already have scaling set at 200%, which increases the size of the gnome interface elements to a comfortable level.  I think the issue is just that nautilus assumes that users will not want to scale icons very much, while other file managers dont