# How to increase the maximal thumbnail size in Ubuntu 20+ nautilus file manager?

Tags: gnome, unity, nautilus, filemanager, thumbnails

The maximum available thumbnail size (~165px) in Ubuntu 20.04 is too small for my liking and I would like to increase it above this limit:
[image: thumbnails in nautilus]
I have tried nautilus, nemo and thunar and in all of them the max thumbnail size is similar and I can't find a way of increasing it.

And no, `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size <npx>` does not work anymore - there is just no such variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nautilus: Show image thumbnails at more than 200% size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-image-thumbnails-at-more-than-200-size)

Comment: No, the answers provided there suggest using gsettings (which don't work anymore) or other managers, but those don't quite do what I want either.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS at the moment. I'll update the details in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same question with you. Seems that the latest version on gnome does not allow the change of thumbnail size as you described. A little more experimentation on my PC and I found the solution myself, so I want to share it here.

through dconf-editor navigate to /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/ There you will find

"use-experimental-views false"

Change that to true (with the knob) and then open nautilus. Use the view options next to show list and you will see that now you can increase the level to 267%

Enjoy

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E29Ox.png)

Comment: Thanks! While not perfect, that is certainly much better than the default setting.